# Extract yes/no checkbox from pdf forms in Python

Tags: python, pdf, ocr, pypdf, data-extraction

I am trying to extract data from a pdf form that includes the answers within checkboxes in the below pdf.  I have tried using pyPDF2 and pdfminer but neither recognize the checkboxes. What is the best way to extract answers in checkboxes? I am able to extract all other data from pypdf2.PdfFileReader using either:

Example Form: https://raec.rocklinusd.org/documents/GradPortfolioFiles/Standard%20Application.pdf

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

pdf=PdfFileReader('/Standard Application.pdf')

pdf.getFormTextFields()

pdf.getFields()
```